# precompiled asp.net website give an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, precompile, pre-compilation

I have one ASP.Net website.As its a website there is separate dll file in bin for each aspx.cs file after publishing the website.So if we want to change anything on live environment we again need to publish whole site.If I try to replace specific page dll then it give me an error.so not able to find out way I just want it build only one dll with application name like aaaa.dll of all  .cs file.Is there any way to make it possible.Its a big project so if I want to make web application from website then it make me cost to much.so if there is any other way then it will be fine for me or how I can make single dll form my website?Any suggestion is welcome. Thnaks.

Comment: This is weird. In a website application you don't have any DLL but the cs files are compiled on the fly. In a webapplication you have just one DLL in the bin folder with all the cs files compiled there. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: you are right but is there any way that i can make it single dll so that it will be easy to redeploy he code on server.

Comment: If you have a website you can convert it to a web application. Is a painful passage, follow this walkthrough https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `File Publish Options` there are many settings available under the "Precompile during publishing" option:

[image]

[image]

If you choose "Merge all outputs to a single assembly" it'll create a single assembly as you are asking.

Comment: OMG! Let me try this one as well.Thanks you save my lots of time.Thanks once again.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error An error occurred when merging assemblies: ILMerge.Merge: ERROR!!: Duplicate type 'aaa' found in assembly 'App_Code'. aspnet_merge 0

Comment: Could you try to right click on the solution and click "Clean Solution"?

Comment: You could also try deleting all the files under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files